# Managing multiple configurations which depend on a singleton shared resource

Tags: terraform

I have multiple different services which each have their own terraform configuration to create resources (in this particular case, a BigQuery table for each service).

Each of these services depends on the *existence* of a single instance of a resource (in this case, a BigQuery dataset).

I would like to somehow configure Terraform so that this shared resource is created exactly once if it does not exist.

My first thought was to use modules, however this leads to each root service attempting to create its own instance of the shared resource due to module namespacing.

Ideally I would like to mark one directory of terraform configuration as dependent on another directory of terraform configuration, without importing that latter directory as a module. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is, you need to create a module and then save the remote state somewhere.  You can configure backends in terraform to handle this for you.  Once you have that you can then have other resources reference that state using the "data_terraform_remote_state" resource.  Any outputs you have configured in the module will be available to reference in the remote state.